# Editing a programatically created datatable asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Good day guys, I am binding asp.net gridview whose datasource table is a programatically created table which gets populated dynamically by getting data from different tables via joins, I want to edit it, **how come I am going to get row index(for editing) as data is coming from different tables And has no unique identifier** as it is just in memory i.e. dataset visualiser, neither hidden field nor datakeynames seems to work, any help please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: When you get data from multiple tables add uniqueidentifier column, and set Guid.NewGuid() value for each row, and then you will have unique column

Comment: @un-lucky I have bolded my exact problem, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev let me try it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataTable GetTableWithUniqueColumn()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table = GetDataFromDB(); //  dynamically getting data from different tables via joins
            table.Columns.Add("UniqueColumn", typeof(Guid));
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                row["UniqueColumn"] = Guid.NewGuid();
            }

            return table;
        }
```

Comment: That has of course answered my question, now I can identify each row in **Programatically Created DataTable** uniquely. On the other hand I was displaying this table in gridview, which has started showing 'UniqueColumn' too, any idea to hide it please.

Comment: After binding datatable to grid datasource this code will hide column gridview1.Columns["UniqueColumn"].Visible = false;

Comment: I tried this already and once again after you specified but **intellisense** says that it will not accept 
`gridview1.Columns["some string here"].Visible=false;` Its needs [int], Anyway to let it accept string because index lets just say can't be determined in advance.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, gridview1.Colums[] waits int index of column. There is other way hiding column by its header name `foreach (DataControlField col in gridReviews.Columns)
        {
            if (col.HeaderText == "Name")
            {
                col.Visible = false;
            }
        } ` try this

Comment: Also it looks like `gridview1.Columns[int].Visible=false` works only for server controls like item template or bound field columns, in my case it is hiding item template column but not dynamically created columns,

Comment: I tried this and worked `table.Columns["UniqueColumn"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;` this code was before binding to gridview. I didnt try after binding. Please tell me if this helped )

Comment: This is for previous comment,
 Same Story this is trying to hide columns generated by server controls like Item Template or Bound fields, as **HeaderText** points to, NOT working for _**UniqueColumn**_ which is not a server control, I also tried
`if (col.GetType() == typeof(Guid))` but we need to somehow specify in
`foreach (somethinghere in gridReviews.Columns)` which says that column is not server control but programatically added column

Comment: I tried it like
`testTable.Columns["UniqueColumn"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;` 
`gridview1.DataSource = testTable;`
`gridview1.DataBind();`

Similarly next time I moved it after setting datasource and next time after databind and next time right after where **UniqueColumn** was added but no use, this is like having no effect at all

Comment: If you can share that page codes I can try it on my pc